# Django join query with related key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this model:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    role_name = models.CharField()

class RolePriviledge(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, related_name='role_priviledge' )        
    module_name = models.CharField()
    priviledge_level = models.CharField()

class UserRole(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
```

What I am trying to do is to find all the priviledges for a specified user.  In sql, this would be:

```
SELECT t3.* 
FROM UserRole t1
JOIN Role t2 on t1.role_id = t2.id
JOIN RolePriviledge t3 on t2.id = t3.role_id
WHERE t1.user_id = USER_ID
```

(I can also skip the join with `Role` and just do an inner join between `UserRole` and `RolePriviledge`)

How would I do this join with Django ORM?  `UserRole.objects.filter(user_id=USER_ID).select_related('role')` would join `UserRole` with `Role`.  How do I join it with `RolePriviledge`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [backward relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

```
privileges = []
user_roles = UserRole.objects.filter(user__id=USER_ID)

for user_role in user_roles:
    privileges.append(user_role.role.role_priviledge.all())
```

`privileges` is a `list` of Querysets.

Comment: There may be multiple UserRoles for a specific User, so `UserRole.objects.get(user__id=USER_ID)` is throwing an error

Comment: Ok. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: This works but would require multiple queries.  Is there no way to do this as one JOIN query (other than doing a raw query)?

Comment: At least I don't find any other way. You can use raw sql.

Comment: @user3628119 If you have multiple `Role` for each `User` then you should use a `ManyToManyField` relation instead of `Foreignkey` relation.

Comment: If I add `user` as a `ManyToManyField` in the `Role` model, I still wouldn't be able to join it with `RolePriviledge` as there is no foreign key from `Role` to `RolePriviledge`, right?

Comment: Add `Role` to `UserRole` as `ManyToManyField`.